# Laravel 5.6 db:seed throws FatalThrowableError : Class 'APP\Todo' not found

Tags: php, database, laravel, factory, laravel-seeding

i am using faker generate to generate fake entries and insert it into database with the help of **php artisan db:seed** when i run this command
  it shows an error :

> Seeding: TodosTableSeeder
>
> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class
>   'APP\Todo' not found
>
> at
>   /var/www/html/todos/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:217
>       213|         if ($this->amount < 1) {
>       214|             return (new $this->class)->newCollection();
>       215|         }
>       216|
>
> > 217|         $instances = (new $this->class)->newCollection(array_map(function () use ($attributes) {
> >         218|             return $this->makeInstance($attributes);
> >         219|         }, range(1, $this->amount)));
> >         220| 
> >         221|         $this->callAfterMaking($instances);
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::make([])
>         /var/www/html/todos/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:167
>
> 2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::create()
>         /var/www/html/todos/database/seeds/TodosTableSeeder.php:15
>
> Please use the argument -v to see more details.

here is my code 
**UserFactory.php**

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Todo::class, function(Faker $faker) {
    return[
        'todos' => $faker->sentence(10)
        ];

});
```

**TodosTableSeeder.php**

```
<?php
use App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class TodosTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        factory(APP\Todo::class, 10)->create() ;
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
    <?php
use App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        //$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
            $this->call(TodosTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `factory(App\Todo::class, 10)->create() ;` instead. Capitalization matters.

Comment: i used it in TodosTableSeeder . what you mean by Capitalization matters?

Comment: Meaning `APP` is not the same as `App`

Answer (score 2):

in `TodoTableSeeder.php`

change `run` method to

```
public function run()
{
    factory(Todo::class, 10)->create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are try to get Class with APP\Todo and APP\Todo not exist because not is correct , the correct form is 
\App\Todo::class

But if you call the class in the header, when you need the class you just need to call it like this: class All :: class

I hope this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue.
The problem was i changed my project name so it can't find App\Todo.
Replace App with your project name as MYTODO/Todo::class.

TodoTableSeeder.php

```
public function run()
{
factory(MYTODO\Todo::class, 10)->create();
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Todo;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class TodosTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        //factory(APP\Todo::class, 10)->create() ;
      factory(App\Todo::class, 10)->create() ;
    //I changed the APP to App
    }
}
```

Comment: This has already been answered both in the comments and two answers. You should at least highlight **why** you changed something such that others can learn from your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a model of your todos app.

In this case, the compiler is looking for App/Todo: means it is looking for todo.php in App folder...

> artisan make:model Todo

^Run this command first.. then you'll see a Todo.php in your App folder. 
after that run your original command.

> `php artisan db:Seed`

Hope it works. worked for me in laravel 7.0.