# Laravel 5.6 - Seeder Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to populate a Laravel 5.6 project DB - following the [offial docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding) - without success. `php artisan db:seed` throws this exception:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'App\Item' not found
>
> at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/greylab/inventario/greylab_inventario/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:217
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::make([])
>         /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/greylab/inventario/greylab_inventario/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:167
>
> 2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::create()
>         /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/greylab/inventario/greylab_inventario/database/seeds/ItemTableSeeder.php:14

I already tried most of the common suggestions provided from the community, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755432/laravel-5-6-dbseed-throws-fatalthrowableerror-class-app-todo-not-found), as well as:

- Trying with `composer self-update` + `composer dump-autoload`;
- On my `composer.json` the `autoload` property is set as is:

`"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},`

(Tried to put classmap in autoload-dev too).

Here's the situation:

**ItemFactory.php**

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

// Definizione dati test
$factory->define(App\Item::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [ ...]
}
```

**ItemTableSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ItemTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Item::class, 25)->create();
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(ItemTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

- At last, I tried to put dependencies directly in sources too:

`use App\Item;
    use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;`

by removing the `App\` prefix and leave only `Item::class` in the argument:

```
factory(Item::class, 25)->create();
```

All these tries didn't helped, so I'm actually stuck. 
If anyone could show me the way, it should be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance to all.

**UPDATE**

@kerbholz & @h-h: There was a mistyped trait in `ItemTableSeeder.php`, thanks for both your suggestion. Yes, in first place I implemented an `Item.php` model like this:

```
<?php

// Definizione Namespace
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

/**
 * Classe Item
 */
class Item extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    // Dichiarazione Proprietà
    protected $table = 'item';
    protected $dateformat = 'Y-m-d';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'data_acquisto',
        'labeled',
        'estensione_garanzia',
        'stato',
        'data_dismissione',
        'note'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'codice',
        'serial',
        'componente_id',
        'tipologia_id',
        'condizione_id',
        'locazione_id',
        'fornitore_id',
        'parent_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'data_acquisto',
        'data_dismissione',
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    /**
     * All of the relationships to be touched.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $touches = [
        'componenti',
        'condizioni',
        'fornitori',
        'locazioni',
        'tipologie'
    ];

    /**
     * Scope query item figli
     * Getter
     * @param array $query Query
     * @return array Query
     */
    public function scopeFigli($query)
    {
        return $query->where('parent_id', '!=', null);
    }

    /**
     * Componenti Correlati
     * Getter
     * @return object Componenti
     */
    public function componenti()
    {
        // Definizione relazione
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Componente');
    }

    /**
     * Condizioni Correlate
     * Getter
     * @return object Condizioni
     */
    public function condizioni()
    {
        // Definizione relazione
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Condizione');
    }

    /**
     * Fornitori Correlati
     * Getter
     * @return object Fornitori
     */
    public function fornitori()
    {
        // Definizione relazione
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Fornitore');
    }

    /**
     * Locazioni Correlate
     * Getter
     * @return object Locazioni
     */
    public function locazioni()
    {
        // Definizione relazione
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Locazione');
    }

    /**
     * Tipologie Correlate
     * Getter
     * @return object Tipologie
     */
    public function tipologie()
    {
        // Definizione relazione
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tipologia');
    }
}
```

Meanwhile I continued to implement others. Now, after correcting the mistype and run again twice a `composer dump-autoload` seeding started. It populated some tables, but after that thrown a new exception. Here's an extract from last try:

```
    Seeding: ItemTableSeeder

   ErrorException  : Illegal offset type

  at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/greylab/inventario/greylab_inventario/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:257
    253|      * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
    254|      */
    255|     protected function getRawAttributes(array $attributes = [])
    256|     {
   257|         if (! isset($this->definitions[$this->class][$this->name])) {
```

@h-h: In this case, I tried to put backslash before "App": `\App\Item::class` with no success. Dunno if it's related to some `faker` misconfiguration...

Comment: `factory(App\Item::class, 25)->create();` should do it. Do you have a model App\Item??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

Inside `ItemFactory.php` I put a stupid `$this` as factory parameter, in a relation creation:

```
$factory->define(App\Item::class, function (Faker $faker) {
[...]
 'parent_id' => function() {
            return factory($this)->create()->id;
        }
}
```

By changing the `return` sentence in this way:

```
return factory(App\Item::class)->create()->id;
```

the issue seems to be solved.

Thanks everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either import the `Item` class like so:

`use App\Item;`

which means you can do this:

`factory(Item::class, 25)->create();`

--

Or put a `\` before hand like so:

`factory(\App\Item::class, 25)->create();`

--

Also make sure your `Item` class has this at the top:

`namespace App;`

Answer (score 0):

Normally **Seeder Class Not Found** error occurs, when we have different git branches and we checkout to new branch.

```
php artisan db:seed --class=StockBranchFileSeeder
```

Exception: *For Target class [StockBranchFileSeeder] does not exist.*
[Seeder Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLdmQ.png)

So I resolved this issue simply run below code in project root;

```
composer dump-autoload
```

now [Seeder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMNBT.png) has been successfully executed.